grub installation
When installing the latest Ubuntu LTS (Jammy Jellyfish), near the end of the installation I get the error message "Executing 'grub-install/dev/sdb' failed.  This is a fatal error."  I get this error message no matter what /dev/ I try.

Does this answer your question? I receive the error 'grub-install /dev/sda failed' while attempting to install Ubuntu as the computer's only OS.

Does this answer your question? After installing Ubuntu on a blank disk it won't boot

This worked for me:
I often get the same grub error when installing Ubuntu on one of my machines.
The solution it seems is a to do manual partitioning setup. Create as follows.
500M fat32 partition with a mount point of /boot/efi
4G of swap (not needed, but I like too) - has to be activated with an entry in fstab
And the rest as ext4 with a mount point of /
Here's some more info if needed.
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-type-of-installation
